# Instance dependent properties best practices for ANT

Tags: java, ant

i am currently writing new build and deployment scripts for several java projects.

I create war and ear files. I have multiple instances and different configuration and property files. 
I want to manage all properties (key/value) at one place. 
What's there the best practise?

My current approach is:
CSV file with the following records per row:

> Destination-File;keyname;value_instance_test;value_intance_qs;value_instance_prod

e.g.

> web.xml;display-name;AppTest;AppQS;AppProd

During the ant build, I am creating a temp file depending on the instance with only key-value and do a [ant filter](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html) on the target file.

Do you have any suggestions? I guess I am not the only one with this requirement and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thank you

Comment: ANT is a build tool and is therefore less suited to deployment. Consider a separate process for your application deployment, one that does not rely on "baking in" the environment specific settings into your EAR and WAR files.

Comment: For example which tool?